# Проблема передачи параметра при ngRoute-роутинге в одностраничном приложении

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angular-routing

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5cdjsALrjBkjQ9TEAXRm?p=preview)

В одностраничном приложении передаю объект в другой контроллер, но не могу его отобразить:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'firstpage.html',
      controller: 'firstpageCtrl'
    })
    .when('/secondpage/:param', {
      templateUrl: 'secondpage.html',
      controller: 'secondpageCtrl'
    });
});
```

**firstpage.html**

```
<div>
  Проблема передачи параметра при роутинге в одностраничном приложении
</div>
<br>
<button ng-click='open2()'>Вторая страница</button>
```

**firstpagectrl.js**

```
app.controller('firstpageCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.open2 = function() {
    var ob = {
      name: 'Adam',
      age: '20'
    };
    $location.path('/secondpage/' + ob)
  };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="firstpagectrl.js"></script>
    <script src="secondpagectrl.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**secondpage.html**

```
<h3>Вторая страница</h3>
```

**secondpagectrl.js**

```
app.controller('secondpageCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams){
  var ob = $routeParams.param; 

  console.log(ob); // -> [object Object]
  console.log(ob.name); // -> undefined
});
```

---

### Вопрос

Как показано выше: различные попытка отобразить объект, полученный в контроллере `secondpagectrl` через параметр отображается не корректно. Что не так?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5cdjsALrjBkjQ9TEAXRm?p=preview)

Comment: а как ты ожидал увидеть в url объект `ob = {
      name: 'Adam',
      age: '20'
    }`?

Comment: @Grundy я подозревал об этом. Но поисковые запросы типа _angularjs how pass `object` to parametr_ и т.п. почему-то приводили на подобный подход и как видно, моя наивность допустила, что видя `{ name: 'Adam', age: '20' }` ангуляр сериализует это добро в json. Так что мне делать? Или как-то post-запросом осуществить роут?

Comment: _ангуляр сериализует это добро в json_ - до ангуляра дело не доходит.  Все ломается на моменте: `$location.path('/secondpage/' + ob)`. При сложении строки и объекта, объект приводится к строке, стандартное значение _[object Object]_